# How to test if JDBC driver is installed correctly and if the DB can be connected?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I tried installing this at home along with Java SDK... The SDK worked fine and I can now use the command prompt to compile java programs into classes...

However I am unsure how to test if JDBC is working to connect to my server/databases/mysql.

As I have a feeling my server (Which is a shared website/webhost) may not allow the connection...

How can I test that the JDBC was installed correctly without having to connect to a server?

And then how can I test (Seperate code please) that the (now confirmed working) JDBC is connecting to my databases?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> How can I test that the JDBC was installed correctly without having to connect to a server?

Just check if `Class#forName()` on the JDBC driver doesn't throw `ClassNotFoundException`.

```
try {
    Class.forName(driverClassName);
    // Success.
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // Fail.
}
```

---

> And then how can I test (Seperate code please) that the (now confirmed working) JDBC is connecting to my databases?

Just check if `DriverManager#getConnection()` or `DataSource#getConnection()` doesn't throw `SQLException`.

```
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)) {
    // Success.
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    // Fail.
}
```

#### See also

- [Exceptions tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)
- [JDBC+MySQL mini tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql/2840358#2840358)

Comment: As per your deleted *"Which `driverClassName` do I need?"* comment: just pick the one you need for the particular database. For MySQL that's usually `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. See also the vendor-specific documentation and the mini tutorial in "See also" section.

Comment: Damn, got a fail. :( Time to reinstall :P

Comment: I'd suggest to get through the mini tutorial to ensure that you've covered (and understood) everything :)

Answer (score 3):

First, download MySQL's [JDBC driver](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) and put it somewhere in your application's classpath.

Second, try to register that driver in your Java code, using

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

If that doesn't throw an exception, you've managed to register sucessfully.

Third, check if your connection works:

```
Connection conn =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","user", "pass");
```

Substitute your URL, username and password as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Install a database locally and connect to that.

You can check the connection to the server by using telnet to connect to the port where the database should be listening; if you can open a connection, you know there isn't a network problem (such as a firewall). If JDBC is okay and the network is okay, then you can try connecting to the remote system. If that doesn't work, it's some kind of configuration problem.